# Static class for shared variables across multiple Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns

I am developing a software in WPF c#. My software has multiple windows. I need to share a same instance of on object across multiple windows (I am using legacy code, so I can not make that object static). Is it a good practice to have a static class which will have variables that I need to share across multiple windows, so I can avoid passing them through a constructor. Thank you

Comment: `Is it a good practice` no, but you could use dependency injection and have one instance shared across the application.  That would be more ideal.  Why do you want to avoid passing them through a constructor

Comment: If you are following a proper MVVM model then the different windows will be sharing the same data context so wont need statics

Comment: All windows doesn't necessarily share the same DataContext. Does this mean that you have one giant view model for all your windows/views?

Comment: @mm8 All windows no, all windows sharing common data should be though

Comment: So all stuff that are related to these windows should be put into the same view model? This is certainly not any better than using a static class or a singleton service to share the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use a static class or you could inject all windows/view models with the same singleton instance. Note that this doesn't necessarily has to be a class that actually implements the singleton design pattern but you need to make sure that you inject the windows/view models with the very same instance.

The latter approach is the preferred one, mainly because a non-static shared class can implement an interface which enables you to easily replace the implementation with another one which in turn makes it a lot easier to unit test your classes.

So it is not, at least in the general case, really a good practice to use a global static class but this might still work in your specific scenario.

Comment: Why use a singleton, when you inject it anyway? You could as well inject a normal instance of a class without it being a singleton. (not the downvoter btw...)

Comment: Then the data isn't shared between the windows/view models since they both have their own instance...

Comment: Why would that be? You can inject the same instance without ever going near a singleton pattern.

Comment: Yes, the class doesn't need to explicitly implement the singleton pattern but you should still only create a single instance of it and that effectively makes it a singleton. This is typically controlled using IoC containers but that's another story.

Comment: Having a single instance does not make it a singleton any more than `int x = 5;` makes `int` a singleton. "Singleton" is a design pattern that is the opposite of a single instance in a DI container. Some DI containers named their static lifetime enum Singleton, that's a naming flaw of those containers, but does not make an instance a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: The thing is that there is no difference if you only create a single instance of the class.

Comment: Yes there is. If I create a single `int`, then it's neither globally available, nor does it hinder maintenance programmers from just creating a *second* `int`. I can pass it around and inject it as I see fit. If I make `int` a singleton, then it's value is globally available *and* restricts the use of further `int`s. I could pass it around, but being globally available, what's the point?

Comment: The main point here is that you inject both windows/view models with the *same shared instance*. Whether the type of this instance is implemented according to the singleton design pattern doesn't matter.

Comment: I agree. More than that, as it works perfectly *without* a Singleton anti-pattern, I would not advise anybody to use it.

Comment: Me neither. So when I mention "singleton" here, I am simply referring to a shared instance of a class. I have edited my answer to clarify this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Don't know why everybody is so angry when you ask a question